# Unhappiness spike

Tags: fallout-shelter

So I recently had a shortage on EVERYTHING, and my vault became unhappy. Although they are all healed and I have full resource bars again, my dwellers that were originally at 90-100% happiness are now at 10%, any tips on how to fix this??[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to raise happiness:

1. Working in room with the same SPECIAL requirement (max 75%)
2. Making a baby (50% boost)
3. Rush a room successfully (10% boost)

Comment: And also the radio room. And a pet that increases happiness (although that might not last after you remove the pet).

Comment: The radio room's happiness boost is... really lame.  The moment you remove the radio operator, everyone's happiness drops, instantlyeven for people started at a 100% before the radio room was operational.  I hate the radio room...

Comment: I agree that thing sucks, but it's still technically a way.

Answer (score 2):

happiness rises if your dwellers are working in an appropriate room.
for example, in the image you posted, a dweller with high S, should work in a room were S is need.